# "If" shorthand on react component

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have a simple logic for check which menu is active.

I'm using:

```
const [activeMenu, setActiveMenu] = useState("0");
```

for the state.

and using if shorthand:

1. `className={activeMenu === "2" && "active"}`
2. `className={activeMenu === "1" ? "active" : ""}`

but the first one gave me:

```
react_devtools_backend.js:4026 Warning: Received `false` for a non-boolean attribute `className`.

If you want to write it to the DOM, pass a string instead: className="false" or className={value.toString()}.
```

My question is why the first one gave me that warning? but my site is still working like charm.
Why is that say that received `false`?

Comment: It's basically just as the error says - it's sometimes a mistake people make.

Comment: @CertainPerformance it say that it is receiving a boolean value, but I don't using any boolean?

Comment: Sure you are. `activeMenu === "2"` evaluates to a boolean

Comment: && "active" is shorthand for `"active" !== null`, so that also is a boolean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if `activeMenu` is not `2`, then className would be `false` (invalid)

```
className={activeMenu === "2" && "active"}
```

with this

```
className={activeMenu === "2" ? "active" : ""}
```

if `activeMenu` is not `2`, then className would be an empty string (valid)

So, it's basically as the error says. className is not a boolean attribute.

run the code below in console, it's basically the same thing as your code. It will return `false`

```
false && "active" !== null
```